# How to automatically pump oil over long distances using ender chests?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

We're playing on Feed the Beast Infinity Evolved 2.6 on minecraft 1.7.10.

In the world we're playing in there's plenty of locations with oil but they're all rather far away from the base.

I have mastered the art of using a pump to pump up the oil and fill a nearby Iron Tank with it.

The question is, using machines, logistics pipes, ender chests, fluid containers, etc. can I automate the emptying of that tank, which is near the original oil field, and transport it back to my base?

The setup I thought I would try building had this on thje oil field side:

1. Something, let's call this machine Y, connected to the tank, which is going to fill oil from the tank into a fluid container
2. A chassis pipe connected to Y with:

   1. An active supplier module, requesting empty fluid containers and injecting into Y
   2. A provider module, providing a filled fluid container after it has been filled
3. A nearby ender chest with a chassis pipe connected with:

   1. A provider module, providing empty fluid containers from the base
   2. An active supplier module, requesting filled fluid containers to the base

Then in my base I would have:

1. Something, let's call this machine X, that would empty a filled fluid container into a tank
2. A chassis pipe connected to X with:

   1. A provider module, providing the empty fluid container after it has been emptied into the tank
   2. An active supplier module, requesting filled fluid containers for injecting into X
3. A nearby ender chest with a pipe chassis with:

   1. A provider module, providing the filled fluid container from the oil field
   2. An active supplier module, requesting empty fluid containers for the chest

The whole process would look like this.

1. I would inject at least 1 empty fluid container into storage at my base
2. This would immediately be requested by the active supplier on the ender chest which would inject it into the chest
3. On the oil field side, once the empty container would appear in the chest, the supplier on Y would immediately request it and inject it into Y, to be filled
4. Once it was filled, the active supplier on the nearby ender chest would request it and inject it into the chest
5. At the base side, once the filled fluid container appeared in the chest, the supplier pipe on X would request it and inject it, for emptying into the tank
6. Once the fluid container was empty, step 2 would start again

Basically the oil field and base would play ping-pong with the fluid container, empty going from base to oil field and filled back.

I would of course provide enough fluid containers so that the whole process was a bit speedier but this was what I had in mind. I can provide the necessary power to all machine by setting up nearby MFE's or MFSU's, I have a couple of spare ones and the necessary converters and cabling.

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out what X and Y must be.

So the question is, is my above setup feasible, and if so, what can I use for X and Y machines, or what do I need to modify to get this working?

I don't need the whole solution, I just need to know what I'm missing (or that I'm on the wrong track), it's fun to tinker with these things :)

Comment: More fancy and reliable system is to build railroad and use railcraft's features to automate it. You then can even ride them, and if you cooperate with other players, you can make rail grid quite fast :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IC2, this machine would be the "Canning Machine."

In my opinion, the better way would be to use the Fluid or Liquid Transposer from Thermal Foundation or to simply use an EnderTank.

Comment: Ender tank! I've missed that, that's the solution I will go for. Thank you!